# Remove duplicates from two linked arrays in Python

Tags: python, duplicates

I have two arrays, one storing names and the other storing the URL associated with that name. However, the list may contain duplicate names and URL's. Traditionally to remove duplicates I would transform both arrays into a set. However, I only wish to delete the element (from both arrays) if the URL's are the same.

For example, if these were the initial arrays:

```
name = ['Bob', 'Mary', 'John', 'John', 'Bob']
url = ['url1', 'url2', 'url3', 'url4', 'url1']
```

I would want this output:

```
name = ['Bob', 'Mary', 'John', 'John']
url = ['url1', 'url2', 'url3', 'url4']
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do this, `name, url = map(list,zip(*list(set(zip(name, url)))))` What this does is it zips `name` and `url`. Removes duplicates using `set`, makes it back into a list. Unzips the lists then maps list to turn the tuples back into lists.

Note: This will not preserve order, but the elements will still be aligned (as in `'John'` will still map to `'url3'`).

Answer (score 1):

```
In [83]: name = ['Bob', 'Mary', 'John', 'John', 'Bob']

In [84]: url = ['url1', 'url2', 'url3', 'url4', 'url1']

In [85]: urls = set()

In [86]: answer = []

In [87]: for n,u in zip(name, url):
   ....:     if u in urls: continue
   ....:     answer.append((n,u))
   ....:     urls.add(u)
   ....:     

In [88]: answer
Out[88]: [('Bob', 'url1'), ('Mary', 'url2'), ('John', 'url3'), ('John', 'url4')]

In [89]: name, url = zip(*answer)

In [90]: name
Out[90]: ('Bob', 'Mary', 'John', 'John')

In [91]: url
Out[91]: ('url1', 'url2', 'url3', 'url4')
```

Answer (score 0):

zip the lists together, essentially creating a pair and then use a set to eliminate the duplicates

```
>>> name = ['Bob', 'Mary', 'John', 'John', 'Bob']
>>> url = ['url1', 'url2', 'url3', 'url4', 'url1']
>>> list(zip(name, url))
[('Bob', 'url1'), ('Mary', 'url2'), ('John', 'url3'), ('John', 'url4'), ('Bob', 'url1')]
>>> x = set(list(zip(name, url)))
>>> x
{('Mary', 'url2'), ('Bob', 'url1'), ('John', 'url4'), ('John', 'url3')}
```

To get the items back in individual lists, use a list comprehension (The only downside is that you'll lose the ordering of the items because of the initial set conversion)

```
>>> a, b = [item[0] for item in x], [item[1] for item in x]
>>> a, b
(['Mary', 'Bob', 'John', 'John'], ['url2', 'url1', 'url4', 'url3'])
>>>
```